# How to login in my iPhone application with instagram?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, instagram

I want to create my iPhone application and I want to register or login in my application with instagram user details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use instagram API (it is public so feel free to use it). They have nice and detailed documentation. The best place to start as you want authentication is here: http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: I just want to logged-in in my own application with instagram credentials. like ant other application having options like login with FB and Twitter.

Comment: Yes. Use instagram authentication api calls from the link I provided to gain an access token and user info and then you can use them as you like so the use logs in. Exactly like twitter and facebook auth solutions.

Comment: link is dead sorry

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api

> Instagram Basic Display is not an authentication solution. Data returned by the API cannot be used to authenticate your app users or log them into your app. If you need an authentication solution we recommend using Facebook Login instead.